# How can I develop on a Python library package while testing it a project using Pycharm + Docker?

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, virtualenv

This is a pretty specific ask, so I'm open to helpful suggestions that get part of the way there.

I have a python project that runs inside a docker container configured to work with the Pycharm debugger. I have a package, installed in a virtual env with pip, used in this project, that I'd like to develop on.

I haven't found a way to link the package into my project's docker container in such a way that I can change the package and have the code update in my project. 
Currently, the debugger works on codepaths that enter into the package, as long as I don't change any code in the package.

These two problems combined make it hard to test changes to the package without installing it over and over.

Is there a better way to accomplish this goal?

Comment: I misspoke, I'm not using a virtualenv anymore now that dependencies are installed in my docker container. Using `pip install -e` worked before moving the project to Docker, but I have can't find a way to make it work now.

Comment: I don't have a complete answer to this yet, but the closest I've gotten is loading my package as a volume, with the destination path set to where pip packages end up installed on the docker container. Using pip install -e as part of my image build didn't work for me,  because I believe under the hood -e uses symlinks, which don't work as expected in docker containers. the above method allows hot reloading package changes, although using the debugger in the package is still pretty hit or miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've covered all the bases I outlined above with this system:

My project structure is:

```
projects
   projectA (my docker project)
   projectB (the library used in my docker project that I want to develop on)
```

1. In projectA: project settings -> project interpreter -> add path mappings -> map local library path to remote install path on container

   ex. **local path:** /user/{username}/projects/projectB **remote path:** /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/projectB
2. In projectA: project settings -> project structure -> add content root (projectB) -> choose mark as **sources**
3. In projectA: mark path on to projectB in container as a volume in dockerfile

   **ex. VOLUME /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/projectB**
4. In projectA: load local library as volume to library installation on container in docker-compose.yml

   ex.

**volumes:**

**- ../projectB:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/projectB**

Using python 3.6 and Pycharm 2018.2

Answer (score 1):

Given the two source trees that should work together:

1. Create a virtual environment for them, `python -m venv vpy`.
2. Activate it, setting relevant shell environment variables, `. vpy/bin/activate`.
3. Install the library, `cd library && pip install -e .`  (`-e` causes pip to remember a pointer to the live source tree.)
4. Install the application, `cd app && pip install -e .`.  (Pip should know you already have the library installed.)
5. Do whatever you need to do, `$EDITOR file.py; pytest; the_app; $SCM commit`.
6. Once it all works correctly, `docker build && docker run`.

I'd leave any interaction with Docker until the very end, once you've convinced yourself you've fixed the library bug or built the feature.  That avoids troubles with your editor and the container disagreeing on paths, and it means you don't need root privileges for any of your ordinary development work.

Answer (score 0):

Install the package in editable mode.

`pip install -e .`

This will allow you to make changes to the code and update the package simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using combination of what @pbskumar proposed and [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

First run your container with option `--volume /path/to/your/package/on/host/:/path/in/your/container`

And then you execute this inside the container:
`pip install -e /path/in/your/container`

It should work.